# How can I utilize Markdown in Team Foundation Server work item text fields?

Tags: tfs

I'd like to utilize Markdown in Team Foundation Server work items for description, discussion and other, bespoke, text input items, particularly to be able to create dynamic checkbox lists, like in GitHub's flavored Markdown syntax:

```
- [ ] Add text input field and label field.
- [ ] Check for valid input.
- [ ] Add "Submit" button.
```

These dynamic checkbox list items should be observed by TFS, so when someone changes their state, the corresponding text item should be updated and eventually being saved to the work item.

How can this be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can't be done; that is not a capability that is present in TFS/Azure DevOps Server.

You should create user stories and create child tasks corresponding to activities needed to be done to complete the user story.

Comment: I see. I'd rather use them for a story's acceptance criteria, so the developer (or a tester) may validate that all the requested efforts have been implemented.

Comment: If the list is for the benefits of the developers, they should be tasks. If it's for the benefit of manual QA testers, it should be part of the test plan/test steps.